# NPE in jax-rs service for jpa query in Spring Boot + Wildfly 10

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, jax-rs, spring-data-jpa, wildfly

I have a simple service on Spring Boot with JAX-RS, JPA. It works fine on Tomcat, but when I deployed in WildFly 10, I get NPE (and Err 500 on web-page) for Services, which used Jpa query for DB. Service that doesn't use jpa-query work fine. Here is my configuration:

pom.xml:

```
groupId>com.github.naut92.animalswebservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>animalsrestservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>AnimalsRestService</name>
    <description>Restful project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>com.github.naut92.animalswebservice.AnimalsRestServiceApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- thymeleaf used case-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- tag::security[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end::security[] -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!--name project for deploying in Enterprise Servers-->
        <finalName>animals-rest</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <!--plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin-->


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.9.Final</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jboss-deploy</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jboss-undeploy</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>undeploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

JerseyConfig class:

```
@ApplicationPath("/index")
@Configuration
    public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig /*Application*/ {
        public JerseyConfig() {
            register(CustomerResource.class);
        }
```

Service class:

```
@Component
@Path("/cust")
public class CustomerResource {
   
    @Inject
    private /*final*/ CustomersRepository customersRepository;

    public CustomerResource(CustomersRepository customersRepository){
        this.customersRepository = customersRepository;
    }

    public CustomerResource() {
    }

    //TEST--------------------------------
    @GET
    @Path(value = "/ajaxtest")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Set<String> ajaxTest() {
        Set<String> records = new HashSet<String>();
        records.add("Record #1");
        records.add("Record #2");

        return records;
    }

    @GET
    @Path(value = "/all")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Collection<CustomersEntity> listCustomers() {
        return (Collection<CustomersEntity>) customersRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/all/{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public CustomersEntity getCustomerById(@PathParam(value = "id") Long id) throws NotFoundException {
        CustomersEntity customer;
        if(customersRepository.exists(id)){
        customer = customersRepository.findOne(id);
        }
        else
            throw new NotFoundException("could not find user '" + id + "'.");
        return customer;
    }
}
```

and ajaxTest() method works fine, but the other two don't work:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.github.naut92.animalswebservice.resourcesService.CustomerResource.listCustomers(CustomerResource.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:139)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:402)
```

I try to used `<exclusions>` for spring-boot-starter-tomcat like in [this](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications) tutorial and spring-boot-starter-websocket, but I aways get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because Jersey isn't being used. You can tell be the exception that RESTEasy (Wildlfy's implementation of JAX-RS) is being used. The reason is because of the `@ApplicationPath` annotation on the `ResourceConfig` class. `ResourceConfig` is an extension of the standard JAX-RS `Application` class. And JAX-RS is designed to pick up an `Application` class that is annotated with `@ApplicationPath`.

So on startup, RESTEasy is creating the application, not Spring Boot. This is the reason for the NPE. RESTEasy creates the resource class, calling the default constructor, where the service is not initialized. And you are trying to call a non-initialized service during the request.

Now I don't know if this will work, as I've never tried to deploy to Wildfly, but the main things you need to fix are:

1. Remove the `@ApplicationPath` so that RESTEasy doesn't pick it up. You can configure the path in your `applicaiton.properties` file. Just use the property `spring.jersey.application-path`
2. You need to make sure your Spring Boot "application" class extends `SpringBootServletInitializer`. This allows the application to be picked up by the container on startup. This is how Spring Boot will initialize the application.

Comment: Yes, it's work! I very appreciate, my friend! I saw, whis is a possible problem in wrong configuration, but not find right decision! Thanks and have a nice friday night! Sorry, my reputation does not allow you to +1.